# Drag an element from an iframe and drop in another iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver, alert

I have two iframes. I have to drag an image from an iframe and drop the image in the other iframe. I tried the below code and its not working

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(fromElement);
builder.clickAndHold(fromElement);
builder.build();
builder.perform();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement pageFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src='components/svg-edit-2.6-unmodified/svg-editor.html']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(pageFrame);
WebElement rightPanel = driver.findElement(By.id("guide_RIGHT_SAFETY_rect"));
builder.moveToElement(rightPanel);
builder.release(rightPanel);
builder.build();
builder.perform();
```

Also tried to move the element using co-ordinates, but that also not work for me. 
 `action.clickAndHold(fromElement).moveByOffset(25, 0).release().perform();` 
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: Specify your website url on which you were working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below mentioned code.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);                                 //Move inside to the frame. 
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//your xpath")); 
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.clickAndHold(from).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();                        //Move outside to the frame.

driver.switchTo().frame(1);                               //Move inside to another frame.
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("guide_RIGHT_SAFETY_rect"));
act.clickAndHold(to).moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();                      //Move outside to another frame.
```

Comment: This isn't working. When i switch to default content, the from element is not found

Comment: Have you entered your correct `xpath` for from element?